# OrientDB: all pairs shortest path

Tags: orientdb, shortest-path

I'm trying to write a OSQL query for computing the length of the shortest path between all pairs of nodes but, since having more than one class in the `FROM` clause is not allowed, I am wondering how I can loop over all the pairs of different nodes.

I tried with this query:

```
SELECT shortestPath($current, $e0, 'BOTH', 'Meets')
FROM Employee
LET $e0 = (SELECT FROM Employee where $current.nt_account > $parent.nt_account)
```

(`nt_account` is the Employee ID).

When I try to execute the query I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Vertex id can not be null
```

Can anybody help me?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
select from (select $b.shortestPath from Employee let $b= ( SELECT shortestPath($parent.current,@this, 'BOTH', 'Meets') from Employee)) unwind $b
```

Comment: It's running, my dataset is pretty large so it'll take some time. If I may ask: what is the different between `$parent` and `$parent.current`? and from `$current` and `@this`? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In this case I think that there is not difference between using $current or @this.
Regarding $parent and $parent.$current you can look at this link http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Traverse.html#context